# URL getRequestParameterMap not working

Tags: java, jsf

I'm using IceFaces 1.8.2 and trying to get a parameter from the URL using:

```
((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
     .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameter(name);
```

This works fine on the inital request. However, when I do a partialSubmit on a component, it stops working. I'm assuming that its to do with how requests are processed when partial submits are done.

Is there a workaround? At the moment, I'm having to

```
((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
   .getRequest()).getQueryString();
```

and manually pass the query string.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't do IceFaces, but this look like clumsy. I'd just look for a way to **bind** those values (parameters) with the model (javabean) so that JSF itself will get/set them.

Comment: We need to make bookmarkable pages..any other way of doing this apart from passing in parameters through URL?
PS. I initally was doing <value>#{param.parameterName2}</value> as recommended in your blog under passing get parameters but I was having problems when you have an outputLink to the same page...it wouldnt refresh the request and the parameter wouldnt be set again. (e.g. if you have a page like getBook?bookId=55 and on that page it refers to another page getBook?bookId=100....it wouldnt call the setter even though the url has changed getBook?book=100)

Answer (score 1):

- why don't you just ignore partial submits. For the sake of bookmarking partial submits shouldn't matter
- for pretty, bookmarkable urls you can take a look at [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)

Comment: What do you mean by ignore partial submits? The whole point of my question is how to get the URL parameter when using partial submits. I  am trying to workout how to create a bookmarkable page using icefaces with partial submits enabled for an ajax experience. Can you use prettyfaces in conjunction with icefaces?
Thanks.

Comment: when you do ajax submits the URL does not change, does it? And yes, I think you can use prettyfaces with icefaces.

Comment: No the URL stays exactly the same which is why I would expect it to work...however, I cannot use managed bean injection of the parameter via faces-config because if you are on page1?bookId=100 and click on a link on page 1 to page1?bookId=200 the page is not refreshed and the request scoped bean stays with value 100. So I was trying to do in the bean code using the Context above...however, I think its a bug in IceFaces as after a partial submit the URL parameters are not in the request map.

Comment: yes, it might be a bug, but I still don't get it why you want to process the URL of partial requests if they do not differ from the URL of the previous normal request.

Comment: The content of the page is conditional on the URL...after the partial submit it reloads the content